# How to compare varbinary in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, comparison, arrays, varbinary

I want to compare `varbinary` type with byte array. I have tried so far:

```
DECLARE @data AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='4283'

Select * from table1 Where bindayData=CAST(@data AS VARBINARY)
```

But this does not work.

I note one strange behavior of this: when I statically use it like

```
Select * from table1 Where bindayData=CAST('4283' AS VARBINARY)
```

then it works fine. But when I declare a variable, it doesn't work.

Please share your ideas.

Comment: In addition to gbn's answer, you should be aware that casting to `VARBINARY` without a length specifier [limits the length to 30](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @data AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='4283'
```

The string constant `'4283'` is non-unicode in the CAST, one byte per character. 
This gives 4 bytes varbinary `0x34323833`

When you use NVARCHAR(MAX), then it changed to unicode `N'4283'`string with 2 bytes per character.
This gives 8 bytes varbinary, something like  `0x0034003200380033`

Comment: Example to what gbn says SELECT '4283',N'4283',CAST('4283' AS VARBINARY),CAST(N'4283' AS VARBINARY)

Answer (score 3):

Using a style of 2 in the convert function does not truncate the final result. It leaves off the "0x" prefex in essence converting the result to a non-binary result.
Please refer to Microsoft's documentation. There is an example at the bottom:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
Select * 
from table1 
Where convert(varchar(max),bindayData,2) like '%4283%'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: The third parameter in [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should only be uaed for when converting date or time.

Comment: @Luuk that is not correct please see the Microsoft documentation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @MichaelRiley-AKAGunny ok i should have scrolled way down.... you are right!

Comment: @Luuk I came across this yesterday. Every day I update the company's Active Directory listings in a SQL table. Not all the fields just certain ones. The objectGUID is saved as a varbinary. I tried searching this field using like and it failed to produce results. In my search for an easy to use query I came across an example using convert with style = 2. It works like a champ.